# Can we use JHipster for enterprise applications without pay any licences

Tags: jhipster

I saw JHipster via Google, and I am wondering that whether JHipster is free for my company or not (because they said that JHipster is OpenSource).
Please help me to answer this, because I will do choose for my company's future plan. 
Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2):

DISCLAIMER this cannot qualify as official legal advice.

The code of the generator itself is under Apache 2 and it is generally considered that the generated code is your own. At least the JHipster team works under this assumption.

Comment: Right and you can see that lot of companies do so : https://jhipster.github.io/companies-using-jhipster/

Comment: By that way, we can use it for generating application and we take our risks without pay any license to JHipster?